# How to publish an [La]TeXified version of an old typewritten book in mathematics?

Tags: publications, research-process, mathematics

I am considering to [La]TeXify an old typewritten book in mathematics. The book contains a lot of mathematical formulae and figures, but it was typed just before the [La]TeX age: its content is very interesting but it is very painful to read, very unfortunately.
Grossly I am thinking of hacking an OCR output to get a LaTeX version of the book: it would be a kind of update of the typing and/or a repackaging of the content. I am wondering whether there is any Journal or something where such work can be accepted.
Any hint is welcome.

Comment: Do you hold the copyright on said book? If not, that would probably be the first thing to sort out...

Comment: I do not hold the Copyright. In fact I spent some time to find the Publisher web site or something: I could not find any. So, I am afraid that it did not survived the numerical age. On the other hand, I guess that its Copyrights were sold to some other publisher, so far I could not figured out which one.

Comment: If it's old enough that the copyright has actually expired, there should be no legal boundary to stop you from publishing a LaTeX version (with the usual caveat: this is not qualified legal advice!).

Comment: Although [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95558/ocr-for-handwritten-mathematics) is about OCR +  LaTeX  for *handwritten* maths, the answers discuss a printed maths textbook, and may be of interest.

Comment: Also see the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570220/ocr-lib-for-math-formulas)

Comment: Have you tried to contact the author? If the publisher really went under (and is not just off the web -- not finding them on Google is a poor excuse), the copyright usually reverts to them (or their estate), so it's up to them to give permission. Even ignoring the legal side (which you shouldn't), their wishes should be respected. It's arguably an extreme case, but Grothendieck is reported to have expressly forbidden a similar effort for his *Éléments* and *Séminaire de géométrie algébrique*.

Comment: Closely related: This question about re-typesetting a paper  (rather than a book) http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/15783/8513

Comment: It's also worth asking a librarian for help in tracking down the publisher.  Typewritten mathematics books were most common from the 1950's through 70's, and I think there are few (if any) mainstream mathematics publishers from that period who have gone out of business completely.  The most likely scenario is that they were bought by a company with a different name (possibly several times in succession).

Answer (score 5):

This material is almost certainly under copyright, so the appropriate thing to do is to get in touch with the publisher and propose this project.  They may, in fact, be receptive and willing to work with you to make this an official new edition.  If they are not interested, then they may at least be willing to give you an official permission for your "remake."

If, on the other hand, the publisher is non-responsive or for some other reason cannot be contacted, then it would be reasonable to assume it's OK to go ahead with the remake and post it informally, e.g., on your personal website.  Because of the copyright issue, no third party is likely to want to publish it, and if the copyright holder eventually decides to take notice and that they don't like what you have done, you may have to take it down (there is, of course, a chance that they may sue instead, but that is relatively unlikely for such a document).  In the meantime, though, it would be a reasonable public service to provide for an apparently abandoned property.

Comment: *if the copyright holder eventually decides to take notice and that they don't like what you have done, you may have to take it down* – Or they may sue you. There is something like an “abandoned property” in copyright law, namely [orphan wroks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_works) but they have to fulfill stronger requirements. As long as the publisher or author are alive or either of them has a legal successor that is findable with reasonable means, the work is very likely not orphaned. Whether these want to communicate with you, should be irrelevant to their legal claims.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft That is certainly true, but also a risk that many academics (including myself) would be willing to take.

Comment: That may very well be, but please do not misinform them and let them make that decision on their own, i.e., let them take the risk knowingly.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I've added clarification to that effect.

Comment: Something you often see when old photos are reprinted is a (prominent!) notice such as "Despite intensive effort, the copyright holders could not be located. They are asked to please contact the publisher where applicable." How much legal weight this carries is open for debate ("none" is always a safe bet), but it does indicate good faith and shifts (part of) the burden of proof onto the suing party. Of course, said effort must have been made (and documented).

Comment: I finally reached the copyright holder. Very unfortunately [s]he has been very uncooperative: I guess [s]he want to jealously keep the copyright even if it was not my point. Whatever. I was very surprised  by the number of answers and the interest brought to the question: I have been hesitating a lot before posting it. So after all it does not look as a crazy idea. Now I am looking for an other old book, a very old one that is in the public domain. Lesson learned.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle Pity, but it sounds like you did the right thing.  Not all copyright holders act thus, however.